# How to style shiny datatable cells by column quantile?

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, dt

I am trying to style cells in a shiny datatable into six or so column-level quantiles (except the first column, which is character). Here is a MRE of my current code, which styles cells as above or below the column mean with a rowcallback from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38052688/15436110). I am not familiar with javascript.

EDIT: users can select/deselect columns, so I need a solution that applies across the columns currently in `dataset`.

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

set.seed(123)
dataset <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:20,
  Value1 = round(rnorm(10, mean = 15, sd = 5), 1),
  Value2 = round(rnorm(10, mean = 25, sd = 8), 1))

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Reprex for cell styling"),
  dataTableOutput("myTable"))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$myTable <- renderDataTable({
    datatable(
      dataset,
      options = list(
        rowCallback = JS(paste0(
          "function(row, data) {\n",
          paste(
            sapply(
              2:ncol(dataset),
              function(i) paste0("var value=data[", i, "]; if (value!==null) $(this.api().cell(row,", i, ").node()).css({'background-color':value <=", mean(dataset[[i]]), " ? '#6EACCA' : '#FFDD91'});\n")
            ),
            collapse = "\n"
          ),
          "}\n"
        ))
      )
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Most of my attempts so far have been similar to:

```
rowCallback = JS(paste0("function(row, data) {\n",
                        "  // Iterate over columns starting from the second column (index 1)\n",
                        sapply(2:ncol(dataset), function(i) {
                          paste0(
                            "  var value = data[", i, "];\n",
                            "  if (value !== null) {\n",
                            "    // Calculate column-level quantiles for the current column\n",
                            "    var columnData = data.map(function(row) { return row[", i, "]; });\n",
                            "    var quantiles = quantile(columnData, [0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8, 1]);\n",
                            "    var color;\n",
                            "    if (value <= quantiles[1]) color = '#BFD3E6';\n",  
                            "    else if (value <= quantiles[2]) color = '#8BACD6';\n",
                            "    else if (value <= quantiles[3]) color = '#6382C1';\n",
                            "    else if (value <= quantiles[4]) color = '#385FAD';\n",
                            "    else if (value <= quantiles[5]) color = '#0D3D99';\n",  
                            "    else color = ''; // Handle edge cases if needed\n",
                            "    $(this.api().cell(row, ", i, ").node()).css({'background-color': color});\n",
                            "  }\n"
                          )
                        }), "}\n"))
```

The closest I have gotten is styling in six quantiles but the cutoffs revert to whole-datatable values instead of column-level quantiles.

Comment: You don't need to resort to JavaScript. You can use the **DT** functions `formatStyle` and `styleInterval`.

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneLaurent, I did initially intend to use the [built in functions](https://rstudio.github.io/DT/010-style.html). But it looks like they don't support column-level calculated quantiles, unless I'm missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **DT** functions `formatStyle` and `styleInterval`:

```r
library(DT)

set.seed(123)
dataset <- data.frame(
  ID = 1:20,
  Value1 = round(rnorm(200, mean = 15, sd = 5), 1),
  Value2 = round(rnorm(200, mean = 25, sd = 8), 1)
)

brks1 <- quantile(dataset$Value1, c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8))
brks2 <- quantile(dataset$Value2, c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8))
clrs <- c("red", "#BFD3E6", "#8BACD6", "#6382C1", "#385FAD", "#0D3D99")

datatable(dataset) %>% 
  formatStyle("Value1", backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks1, clrs)) %>%
  formatStyle("Value2", backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks2, clrs))
```

Comment: Thank you! How can this be generalizable to any number of columns though? I just included two set columns for the purpose of a shorter MRE, but app users can select any number of columns so I need something that would apply across all current columns (excepting the first column). I will edit the question to clarify

Answer (score 0):

Got this working with help from @StéphaneLaurent's answers above and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50922605/15436110). Using a list of quantiles for current columns and a styling loop:

```
    quantileList <- lapply(dataset[, -1, drop = FALSE], function(col) {
      quantile(col, c(0, 0.2, 0.4, 0.6, 0.8))
    })
    
    clrs <- c("red", "#BFD3E6", "#8BACD6", "#6382C1", "#385FAD", "#0D3D99")
    
    DT <- datatable(dataset)

    for (i in 2:ncol(dataset)) {
      brks <- quantileList[[i - 1]]
      colname <- colnames(dataset)[i]
      DT <- DT %>% formatStyle(colname, backgroundColor = styleInterval(brks, clrs))
    }
    
    DT
```